# How to get variable definition/quality png based on html?

Tags: javascript, angular, image, png, converters

I need to parse some DOM nodes to PNG images. 
I am currently using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image, which work fine. Nonetheless, I need to change resolution of the image, like 800 px or 1400 px. With that library one can set the width and height but it doesnt change the content of the html, just the background gets bigger.

How to get HTML DOM node to PNG image in variable resolution?

I am using the following versions: 
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.9.0
Angular: 4.4.6
Typescript: 2.3.4

Comment: I think you can use <picture> tag to solve your problem. For more you can visit
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_picture.asp

Comment: Thanks but that is almost exclusively on image right? 
I need to render the DOM elements, which are not necesarily images.

Comment: You should share the link of html-to-png library that you are using, if you google that names there are plenty of online converters, but I am not sure what tool you are using. Also it would be good if you share the programming language and versions that you are using.